# How should we deal with ill-founded questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, poll

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/group-with-an-endomorphism-that-is-almost-abelian-is-abelian) on the parent site.

Somewhat related to [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-to-deal-with-cranks), but people who ask ill-founded questions are not necessarily cranks.

People will continue to ask questions like "how do I prove X?" for false statements X. What is the best way to deal with such questions?

Answer (score 12):

They should be answered with a proof or explanation of why X is false/unprovable.

Answer (score 1):

They should be closed as "not a real question," because they demand the impossible.

Comment: I'd say answering in the comments is best. If the question was well-thought out and well-written, I'm sympathetic; in this case, since there is no motivation for the question, my inclination is to close it.